# Decorating a concrete class, bad practice?

Tags: java, decorator

Typical uml diagram of the **decorator design pattern** are like so : https://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern

they show the decorator being around an interface.

Question is, does it really matter that it is an **interface** or a **concrete class**?

To begin with a decorator is not supposed to nitpick at the wrapped object behaviour, it's simply a layer of functionality. So I don't see how that's any riskier than using interface.

Typically I would (like to) decorate like so:

```java
class Foo{
    public void doSmth(){
    }
}
class LoggedFoo extends Foo{
    private Foo wrappedFoo;
    public LoggedFoo(Foo foo){wrappedFoo = foo;}
    @override
    public void doSmth(){
        System.out.println("doSmth start");
        wrappedFoo.doSmth();
        System.out.println("doSmth end");
    }
}
```

I don't think we should eye ball concrete class inheritance at the mere sight of it because "it's dangerous". 
So, interface or concrete class, does it matter **here**?

Comment: It doesn't matter ever--the point is, as always, that it's generally cleaner to implement interfaces, avoiding being locked to a concrete class.

Comment: Interfaces allow a class to implement multiple interfaces, but the concrete class doesn't

Comment: Well, a decorator only ever extends one class

Comment: It "matters" in the sense that this is not the decorator pattern.

Comment: Michael Are you saying that because I've left out the "abstract decorator" element between Foo and LoggedFoo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending a class can have unintended side effects.

If Foo already has a constructor (or multiple) you have to implement those too and call the super class.

Additionally, if Foo has private state or side effects in the constructor, those now get executed *twice*. Once for the Foo passed in the constructor and once for the LoggedFoo, which is also a Foo.

It could get messy and lead to bugs and increased resource consumption, but that depends entirely on the class. If the class behaves like an interface (default constructor, no side effects, no state) it might not directly be a problem. But at this point it would just be a subclass that calls through to an other instance, which may be a handy construct but I wouldn't call it using the decorator pattern.

Comment: That's an interesting aspect

Comment: @Sheed This class now *wraps* a Foo, let's call that foo1, and it *is* a Foo itself: foo2. So when you use this class there are at least two Foo's in existence. Decorating interfaces does not have this effect.

Comment: Yes I deleted my comment after realizing that private members could still exist and be initialized without me calling the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It matters because the whole idea of `Decorators` is to add functionality without going the implementation inheritance route. If you are okay with implementation inheritance and risking changing the existing behavior of the object then there is no need for a decorator at all.

The whole idea is to extend the functionality without breaking existing behavior which implementation inheritance does.

Comment: The contract around a class is written at the highest level in the inheritance hierarchy, whether the top level parent is an interface or a class. This contract could also be broken if the parent were an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using interfaces because that is the better practice. They're easier to test and to change the implementation. What if you want to use different type of logger in production (Database, file, console etc.)?

Comment: In case of different loggers, I would just decorate the same way, an Instance of LoggedFoo can be decorated without a hitch with another decorator.